# How to train for triathlons during business travel

Tags: training, swimming, bicycling

I'm a quite avid triathlete.  I do work with a coach and typically peak my training weeks at around 16 hours.

At one time, not too long ago, I was a traveling consultant.  At times I would be on the road 3-4 weeks out of the month, typically Sunday night through Friday.  To add to this, rarely did I visit the same place twice and most times travel involved airplanes (as opposed to driveable destinations).  Luckily for the past 18 months, I have not been on the road.

When I did travel, I struggled with maintaining my training schedule.  I can basically run anywhere.  But, I had a hard time doing the bike portion and definitely finding a pool.  Since then, I have found the www.swimmersguide.com website which is a great resource for finding pools and pool information.

What I am looking for is advice from other travelling professionals who are able to maintain 2-3 swim workouts and/or 2-3 bike workouts during the week while traveling for business, in the event that my travels start back up.

At one time, I am told, it was economical (albeit a pain) to travel with a bike.  That doesn't seem to be the case anymore.  Some airlines (like Southwest and Frontier) are very bicyclist friendly.  Most are not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used to travel a lot, and to be able to bike I looked at hotel with gym onsite, allowing me to have an hour in the evening or early morning, depending of my schedule.

For the swimming I always spend a little bit of time on google maps trying to find a pool that I could hit during lunch break.

Comment: thanks for the information. Stationary bikes don't excite me at all, but I guess that is always an option. I was hoping to get advice on using my actual bike. When I traveled, sometimes I was 90 miles from any pool other than the super-short ones that hotels offer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to carry you bikes with you, one option is take a portable trainer with you (several makers and models are avaialble). You can unfold it in your Hotel room, balcony or any other suitable location, and ride on.

For running - you only need your running shoes.

I think it's most important, that while on a business trip, since it's not your regular schedule, it's easier to get injured, so better be extra cautious.

HF

Answer (score 0):

I have always rented a bike when I am in business trips over the US I go often to the bay area and I rent from blazzing-saddles which has some pretty descend triathlon bikes.

I once put an ad in craiglist to rent a bicycle for a week (or the time of my business trip) and the guy let me use it for free and train with him... In Europe (where I live) I ask to travel by train and pack my own bike even if it mean to take a overnight train...

For swimming I try to look for swimming pool around but not too much since this is nomy strongest  and running that can be done everywhere (yeah I did even run once on the side of a freeway getting lost)